# Argument of type "SQLCHAR" is incompatible with parameter of type "SQLCHAR *"

Tags: c++, sql

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    

    SQLHSTMT retrieveNumber;
    SQLUINTEGER IDNumber;
    SQLINTEGER IDNumberInd = 0;
    SQLRETURN rc;


    // Tried creating SQLWCHAR here to input to SQLPrepare but gives me:
    // 'argument of type "SQLWCHAR" is incompatible with parameter of type "SQLWCHAR *"'
    wchar_t text{ *"SELECT * FROM Table_1" };
    SQLCHAR statementText1{ text };



    SQLPrepare(retrieveNumber, statementText1, SQL_NTS);
}
```

I'm trying to get the SQLPrepare to work but like in the title it says
"argument of type "SQLCHAR" is incompatible with parameter of type "SQLCHAR *".

I tried at the start just putting the text in the arguments but that resulted in saying
"const char =/= sqlchar".

Note I'm following along with the Microsoft Docs for ODBC:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/handles?view=sql-server-ver15

and my experience with c++ goes as deep as going through the [www.learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com) website which I'm not done with, so although there are a lot of similar questions with answers to me it's still confusing.

Comment: You seem to be confusing characters with pointers to characters.

Comment: You'd get the same error with `char` and `char*` or `int` and `int*`

Comment: what do you have the `*` before your literal string? You are dereferencing a char* and turning it into a char.

Comment: thanks for the comments, clearly my head wasn't screwed on properly at the time. I've got a comment in the first answer by Remy Lebeau that I'd appreciate a response as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `text` and `statementText1` variables are declared all wrong.

You are dereferencing a pointer to a *narrow* string literal, thus accessing its 1st `char`acter, which you then assign to `text`, which is declared as a *single* `wchar_t`.

You are then assigning that `wchar_t` to `statementText1`, which is declared as a *single* `unsigned char`.

You are then passing that single character to `SQLPrepare()`, but it expects a pointer to a (non-const) null-terminated string instead, thus the compile fails.

Try this instead:

```cpp
const SQLWCHAR *statementText1 = L"SELECT * FROM Table_1";
SQLPrepare(retrieveNumber, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(statementText1), SQL_NTS);
```

Or:

```cpp
SQLWCHAR statementText1[] = L"SELECT * FROM Table_1";
SQLPrepare(retrieveNumber, statementText1, SQL_NTS);
```

Comment: thank you, however for me it requires to use const before SQLWCHAR as yours ends up saying "const wchar_t cannot be used for SQLWCHAR". is that nothing to worry about?

Comment: My bad, I just realized another thing now it says
"argument type const SQLWCHAR* is incompatible with parameter type "SQWLCHAR*"
I fixed it by removing const and doing
`SQLWCHAR* statementText2 = (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT * FROM Table_1";`
I'm not confident to edit the answer so I'll leave it for others to make sure this is fine, then choose this answer.